# Timezone and group

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My problem is there are 160 entries published at today but i see only 13 entries when i print entries_count. I guess it is about timezone. My timezone is Athens. Any help will be appreciated. I spent my whole day to fix this.

```
@from_date = Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day
@to_date = Time.zone.now.end_of_day

@entries_by_date = Entry.where(:published_at => @from_date..@to_date).group("date(published_at)").select("date(published_at) as date, count(*) as entries_count")
```

view

```
% (@from_date.to_date..@to_date.to_date).each do |day| %>
 <% a= @entries_by_date.detect {|entry| entry.date == day} %>
 <% if a %>
  <%= a.entries_count %>
 <% else %>
  0
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Update:

Time.zone.now can be any date Time.zone.now is for example.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to match on day/month/year.  Try this:

```
@entries_by_date = Entry.where(:published_at => @from_date..@to_date).
                         group("year(published_at), month(published_at), day(published_at)").
                         select(" year(published_at)  as year,
                                 month(published_at)  as month,
                                   day(published_at)  as day,
                                            count(*)  as entries_count")
```

then the view:

```
<% (@from_date.to_date..@to_date.to_date).each do |date| %>
 <% a= @entries_by_date.detect {|entry| entry.day   == date.day  && 
                                        entry.month == date.month && 
                                        entry.year  == date.year} %>
 <%= a.try(:entries_count) || 0 %>
<% end %>
```